# 2 Product Tabs w/ different views

Tags: magento-1.9, products, tabs

I'm looking for a way to have  2 Catalog > Product Tabs.

So one would be

Catalog > Product - Sales

Catalog > Products - Internal

Comment: Could you explain better what you need? It makes no sense to duplicate the catalog without any goal or change the information for one of the versions.

Comment: Sure. I have 8 different departments that we do data entry in for data entry.

Overall I'm looking for a way to show Catalog -> Manage (Departments), give the permission,  the proper grids views, groups, attributes that apply to the departments would be setup and have 0 access to any other areas except what rules where written around what groups would be seen, what attributes where required abdnd what tab you could you use. 

In the backend, the several API and reports we use would work as usual. We have tools to help with grids, but its not the same.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to make the entry of the data easier, just update your attribute set:

Go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets` and add the two new groups "Products - Sales" and "Products - Internal" and assign the attributes needes for sales and needed for internal use.

[image: attribute set]

If you then open a product again, you will the groups as tabs there:
[image: product tabs]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's a little more involved than this, see above.